# Ascender/descender help for brand specifics

Tags: typography, alignment, branding

[image]

Hello everyone!

I'm designing for a brand that requires left-justification for all text, which can make consideration for ascenders and descenders a nightmare. Typically this brand calls for tight spacing, so the closer leading is preferred. However it makes the left justification look visually off even though it technically aligns.

Any advice or suggestions would be most appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Great first question! Welcome to the community.

Comment: imho, what's more distracting than the T over L is the l to y spacing.

Comment: Problem here is that the upper line should be further to the left, but then the y would touch the l. Unsolvable really with this tight leading.

Comment: Only thing I can think of doing is sprinkling it with a little letter/word spacing where appropriate.

Comment: Is there a tt ligature that could help you squeeze "Little" a little?

Comment: ... or deliberately drop the font size for "Little" (a play on words) so you can fine tune the left alignment without the hassle of the l/y clash.

Comment: Is there a way that you could change, "Little" to "li'l" and it plays on the fact that there is little time, displaying that with abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

if the characters overlap, make that part of the brand. I personally wouldn't do it, but if you make it intentional and write it into the Brand Guide, why not make it a thing.

If you do make the characters overlap, you would have to decide which character takes precedence / goes over the other. Would the dark green go over the white, or vice versa.

Ultimately, the legibility is key. If you're typesetting catchphrases like this using the tight settings, and it just simply becomes illegible, then the brand itself needs amending. I'm not being flippant.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!